# Как сделать чтобы информация бралась из github в json файла в режиме онлайна?

Tags: python, json

Как сделать чтобы допустим была онлайн обновление или проверка файлов которые есть в github'e? Типо, если нету файла то она докачивает её, или же допустим лист серверов, типо надпись обнавлялась на "Онлайн" или "Технические работы", как мне сделать чтобы она проверяла в live-режиме?

Py-Code для удобство:

```
from colorama import init, Fore #|
from colorama import Back       #|
from colorama import Style      #|
import msvcrt                   #|
import subprocess               #|
import sys                      #|
import os                       #|
import time                     #|
import getpass                  #|
import json                     #|
#-----------Библы----------------/

# Открываем JSON
with open('C:/ELauncher/settings.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
# Забираем имя из словаря
username = data['username']
version = data['version']
serverselect = data['serverselect']
alts = data['alts']

os.system("title 〡ELauncher • Ядро: SCore")

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
print("")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print("              \033[41m     От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate     \033[0m")
print()
print("\033[94m╔\033[0m Никнейм:", username)
print("\033[94m╠\033[0m Сервер выбран:", serverselect)
print("\033[94m╠\033[0m Версия:", version)
print("\033[94m•\033[0m Выберите пункт:")
print(" 1: Старт игры")
print(" \033[93m2\033[0m: Лист аккаунтов")
print(" \033[91m3\033[0m: Выбор версии")
print(" \033[91m4\033[0m: Настройка лаунчера")
print(" q: Выход с лаунчера")
def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

current_directory = 'C:/ELauncher'
my_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'start.bat')

while True:
    key = get_char()
    if key == "1":
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("              \033[41m     От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate     \033[0m")
        print("")
        print("Нажмите на enter если вы уже водили никнейм.")
        print("Введите ник для создание нового аккаунта:")
        username = input("• ")
        if username =="":
        # Открываем JSON
            with open('C:/ELauncher/settings.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                # Забираем имя из словаря
                username = data['username']

        else:
            # Обновляем значение в json
            data = {}
            data ['username'] = username
            # Записываем обновленные данные в файл
            with open('C:/ELauncher/settings.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
               json.dump(data, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("              \033[41m     От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate     \033[0m")
        print("")
        print("Ник:", username, "выполняется вход...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("              \033[41m     От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate     \033[0m")
        print("")
        print("Проверяем обновление...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Проверяем файлы игры...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        subprocess.run([my_path, username])
        time.sleep(2.5)
        break
        #time.sleep(2.5)
    elif key == "2":
        option = "Лист аккаунтов"
        print("")
        print("ッ Аккаунты:")
        print("", alts)
        print("")
    elif key == "3":
        option = "Выбор версии"
        print("")
        print(Fore.RED + "ッ Пункт «Выбор версии» в разработке.")
        print("")
    elif key == "4":
        option = "Настройка лаунчера"
        print("")
        print(Fore.RED + "ッ Пункт «Настройка лаунчера» в разработке.")
        print("")
    elif key == "q":
        break

        print(option) # no response
```

Comment: Берете requests, делаете get запрос на raw адрес файла на гитхабе. Если его нет - будет 404 ошибка, если есть - разбираете как json.

Comment: А можно пример? Я новичок не понимаю в этом деле :{

Comment: Пример: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Как получить raw адрес - открываете файл на гитхабе, справа над ним видите кнопочку Raw, кликаете по ней правой кнопкой, выбираете "скопировать адрес" (или что-то в этом роде). Или тыкаете на эту кнопку, копируете адрес из адресной строки.

Comment: @insolor я как и не могу понять даже из wiki страницы(